# After insert trigger setting value from another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables one residence the other a sales tax rate table where the primary key is zip code the other is a residence table with a column for zip code and sales tax rate

When I insert a residence record I want the sales tax rate to be updated from the sales tax rate table

Using workbench I created a after insert trigger but I get a syntax error

[Trigger Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwgzp.jpg)

What is wrong with this code

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just copy paste the short code into the question and remove the link.

But to directly answer your question, MYSQL syntax for an update using a join should read:

```
UPDATE Table
JOIN Other
ON Table.x = Other.x
SET Table.column
WHERE stuff as necessary
```

Yours is simply out of order, and the FROM line is not required.